# CVS certificate authentication

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, ldap, certificate, cvs

I have Ubuntu `CVS` server running and the users access the repositories from `Eclipse` with `LDAP` credentials. I'm asked to do a certificate kind of login to CVS from eclipse along with ldap credentials. For this, I recommended changing the group permissions of CVS repo or disabling such users who are not allowed to access repos, but the idea of doing so didn't grab much interest of developers. Does anybody know how logging to cvs with some sort of certificate along with user credentials(ldap) via eclipse and the users who have no certificate are not allowed to connect?.

Thank you!

Comment: Could anybody tell me if it's really possible to have some sort certificate login with CVS.

Comment: CVS is falling out of favour with a lot of people, and has been replaced in most places with either a cvs-like version control system like SVN or a distributed version control system like Bzr or Git, amongst others. These have better security aspects than CVS had, and numerous other benefits.. This is probably why you're getting so few responses. Also, since this is a system configuration issue, you might be better off asking on http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into setting up CVS with Stunnel? Stunnel can do the certificate verification for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cvs over ssh you can do it in two ways.

The simplest way is to simply enable public-key encryption only (i.e. disable password).  Though the certificate is no longer managed by the a certificate authority.

Another approach, though more complicated is to use the gssapi-with-mic support on SSH within Eclipse.  This will allow you to use another mechanism (namely your certificates) to authenticate the connection to the remote server.

Comment: I should compromise to this if I didn't get any!

Comment: I could try ssh-key login as I already tried this before. could you elaborate a bit regarding `gssapi-with-mic` support of eclipse if possible that how it would differ from ssh-key?.